# Filing tax return as dependant or independant

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I filed as independant last year believing that I was an independant student.  This year I talked to my school financial aid director and they told me that under New Jersey State Law, I am still considered a dependant until I am over 24 because I am still a full time student.  I don't live with my mother and she doesn't claim me on my tax return. I work and pay rent.

1. What do I do about applying independant last year and getting a
   return?
2. What do I do this year when I am applying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a significant condition for your parents to be able to [claim you as a dependent](http://www.state.nj.us/treasury/taxation/njit4.shtml):

> You must have paid one-half or more of the tuition and maintenance
>   costs for the student. Financial aid received by the student is not
>   calculated into your cost when totaling one-half of your dependent’s
>   tuition and maintenance. However, the money earned by students in
>   College Work Study Programs is income and is taken into account.

If you work and pay your own tuition or more than half of your total expenses - you're on your own and not anyone's dependent.

Comment: Even if they paid more than half, for whatever reason, if they say they are not claiming him, can't he still claim himself, his own exemption?

Comment: @Joe no, if he can be claimed by someone else - he cannot claim himself even if they don't.

Comment: So I will claim this year as dependant, but what am I suppose to do about last years, and what do I do about my mother not claiming me on hers? If I file dependant there will be inconsistencies and I fear legal issues.

Comment: @ProgramorProgram worst case they'll adjust the returns for both of you and will give a refund to your mom and demand more payment from you. For the IRS - that's a wash, so I doubt anyone would bother. You can go and ask a professional (EA/CPA licensed in your state) for a qualified professional advice.

Answer (score 2):

People in his/her position should not be giving you tax advice.

You work and are not being claimed on another person's taxes. That's enough to file as a single person on your own. You will have your own exemption and standard deduction. If you were not claimed on mom's return for 2012 you should have filed this way then as well. 
You can still file an amended return to get a refund if you paid tax you shouldn't have. And you might want to send the 'director' our way, we'll set him straight.